# Move tear out tabs between Chrome windows in AwesomeWM

Tags: linux, google-chrome, archlinux, awesome-wm

When AwesomeWM is set to a tiling layout, it's very difficult (possible even impossible) to move a tab between Chrome windows.

As soon as you tear out the tab from one window by clicking and dragging the tab, Awesome tiles it which means that you can't drag it into the tab bar of the destination window.

Is there anything that I can do in my Awesome config to fix this? I assume I need to make the window float, but how can I do this and how can I still retain the tiling in all other circumstances?

Answer (score 4):

Your friend will [awful.client.floating.toggle](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.client.html#client.floating.toggle) function. You can bind it to a hotkey, in the default configuration is `modkey+ctrl+space`, check [source code](http://git.naquadah.org/?p=awesome.git;a=blob;f=awesomerc.lua.in;h=2d61b31b00611c9212f6603d32796e5d45138cd0;hb=HEAD#l279).

With default settings you can set float property (and behavior) of a client with press `modkey+ctrl+space`, and after you can move over the main chrome-window.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of not being able to attach a chrome tab to another chrome window for me.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome or Awesome at this time. This problem has been around for a while now: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159628

The problem only happens on one of my monitors for me. I submitted the issue to Google, but chances are they may not fix it anytime soon. You may want to consider using another browser or window manager until this issue is fixed.